# Is there a docker inspect in docker python apis?

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I would like to get the ipaddress of the containers and I trying to figure out how using python docker APIs.

Something like this I would like to do it in python APIs

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

I tried this and coming back null for ip address

```
import docker
dockerClient = docker.from_env()

client = docker.APIClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
for container in dockerClient.containers.list():
    print container.id
    print "-------------"
    print client.inspect_container(container.id)['NetworkSettings']['IPAddress']
```

Comment: You almost never want the container-internal IP addresses for anything: they change routinely and are unreachable in many common circumstances.  Why are you trying to look this up?

Answer (score 7):

```
import docker 
client = docker.APIClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock') 
my_c = client.inspect_container('id_container')
print(my_c['NetworkSettings']['Networks']['bridge']['IPAddress'])
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `docker-py`, you can check the following

- [Inspecting
  Container](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#docker.api.container.ContainerApiMixin.inspect_container)

Try the following:

```python
print client.inspect_container(container.id)['NetworkSettings']['Networks']['bridge']['IPAddress']
```

> Note that you may want to loop on the `Networks` (in case you have multiple network and you want all IPs) or change `bridge` to the appropriate network name as `bridge` will be the default network name.

Comment: In version 3.7.2 it will be something like 
client.api.inspect_container('elasticsearch')['NetworkSettings']['Networks']['dockerfiles_default']['IPAddress']

Comment: @VasiliPascal the `client.api.inspect_container` is not document yet, am i right ? I just don't want to add an updated answer unless its confirmed

Comment: Probably docs were not updated,  I found it using ipython, (python3)